# Can a solution to this parameterized ODE converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Does there exists some $\gamma \ge 0$ such that the solution to the following ODE converges to 0 as $t \to \infty$?
$$y'(t) = \alpha y(t) - \gamma \sigma(t) (1-y^2(t))$$

We are also given y(0) = 2/3, $\alpha > 0$, $t_\sigma > 0$ and $\sigma(t) = 1/\left(1+e^{2(t-t_\sigma)}\right)$.

Note that if $\gamma = 0$, the solution blows up to infinity. While if $\gamma$ is large enough, $y$ quickly becomes negative. I want to know if there is some critical $\gamma$ which balances perfectly such that $y$ neither blows up nor becomes negative.

Wolfram Alpha is able to solve the ODE. However, [the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y%27%28t%29+%3D+ay%28t%29+-+b%2F%281%2Be%5E%282t%29%29+*+%281-y%28t%29%5E2%29) is enormous, and contains the hypergeometric function. Therefore, I don't think solving the ODE for this particular $\sigma$ is the best approach. I suspect the relevant properties of $\sigma$ are being analytic, $0 < \sigma(t) < 1$, $\sigma'(t) < 0$ and $0 < \int_0^\infty \sigma(t) dt < \infty$.

I got the problem while constructing a hard case for low rank matrix reconstruction with gradient descent. Concretely, if such a $\gamma$ always exists, it would imply a lower bound on the sample complexity required to reconstruct low rank matrices in a commonly studied setting, considered for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.15013).

Comment: I think the following should be true (maybe I can prove it but I should check many details): for every $\gamma \geq 0$, there is a unique solution $y_\gamma$ of the ODE such that $0 \leq y_\gamma \leq 1$ and $y_\gamma (t) \to 0, t \to \infty$. Let $f(\gamma)=y_\gamma (0)$, then $f(0)=0$ and (formally), $f(\infty)=1$ so that there is  $\gamma$ with $f(\gamma)=2/3$ ($f$ should be continuous).

Comment: Yes, this works if we can prove that $y_\gamma$ is well defined and $f$ is continuous. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: Let me explain what I have in mind. Given $\gamma$ the function $y_\gamma$ satisfies $y(t)=Ty(t)=\gamma e^{\alpha t}\int_t^\infty \sigma (s)(1-y^2(s))e^{-\alpha s} ds$. $T$ has a fixed point in the set $C_\gamma$ of positive continuous functions less than 1, for $ t \geq t_\gamma$ where $\gamma \int_{t_\gamma}^\infty \sigma \leq 1/4$ ($T$ is a contraction). This gives $y_\gamma$ for $t \geq t_\gamma$ and now we solve backward to $0$ using initila value $y_\gamma(t_\gamma)$.

Comment: This solution must lie below the profile where $y'=0$ (defined by $\alpha y-\gamma \sigma (1-y^2)=0$): if it is above in a point then increases from that point on  and cannot be bounded by 1 near infinity. Computing the profile (the shape of $\sigma$ is quite ininfluent) one sees that is below 1 and gives $y_\gamma (0) \in [0,1]$. Actually $y_\gamma$ tends to 0 at infinity, and here one needs that $\sigma (t) \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and the proof splits in some steps. In what follows $\sigma$ is just positive, decreasing and in $L^1(0, \infty)$.

1. If $y$ is a bounded solution of the ODE (forgetting the initial condition), then
   $$
   y(t)=\gamma e^{\alpha t}\int_t^\infty \sigma (s)(1-y^2(s))e^{-\alpha s}\, ds
   $$
   and $y(t) \to 0$ at infinity.

This follows by writing $(e^{-\alpha t} y)'=-\gamma \sigma (t)(1-y^2)e^{-\alpha t}$ and integrating from $t$ to $\infty$. If $|y| \leq M$, the formula above yileds $|y(t)| \leq \gamma \alpha^{-1}(1+M^2) \sigma (t)$.

2. If $t_\gamma $ is choosen so that $\int_{t_\gamma}^\infty \gamma \sigma (s) \, ds \leq \frac 14$, then there exists a unique solution $y_\gamma$ defined for $t \geq t_\gamma$ satisfying $0 \leq y_\gamma \leq 1$. This follows from a contraction argument considering the map
   $$
   Ty(t)=\gamma e^{\alpha t}\int_t^\infty \sigma (s)(1-y^2(s))e^{-\alpha s}\, ds
   $$
   from $C=\{y:[t_\gamma, \infty[\mapsto [0,1]\}$ into itself which is a contraction for the sup-norm, by elementary computations as above.
3. Now I consider the profiles where $y'=0$, given by the quadratic expression $\alpha y-\gamma \sigma (1-y^2)=0$. The upper profile is $$\frac{-\alpha +\sqrt{\alpha^2 +4\gamma^2 \sigma^2}}{2\gamma \sigma}= \frac{s}{1+\sqrt{1+s^2}}, \quad s=2\gamma \alpha^{-1} \sigma.
   $$
   Note that $0 \leq \phi \leq 1$ and $\phi$ is decreasing in $t$ (since it is increasing in $s$ and $\sigma$ is decreasing). In particular, $\phi$ is a subsolution of the ODE.

The lower profile is negative.
A solution is decreasing when it is between the two profiles, increasing outside.

4. The solution $y_\gamma$ constructed in 2. for $t \geq t_\gamma$ can be continued to $[0, t_\gamma]$ and satisfies $0 \leq y_\gamma \leq \phi \leq 1$ for every $t \geq 0$.

In fact, if $y_\gamma (t_0) \geq \phi (t_0)$, then $y_\gamma \geq \phi$ after $t_0$, by comparison and then $y_\gamma$ would be increasing for $t \geq t_0$ and could not  vanish at infinity.

5. The solution $y_\gamma$ depends continuosly on $\gamma$. In fact if $y_i=y_{\gamma_i}$
   \begin{align*}
   y_2-y_1=&\gamma_2 e^{\alpha t}\int_t^\infty \sigma (s)(y_1^2-y_2^2) e^{-\alpha s}ds +(\gamma_2-\gamma_1)e^{\alpha t}\int_t^\infty \sigma (s)e^{-\alpha s}ds\\
   &-(\gamma_2-\gamma_1)e^{\alpha t}\int_y^\infty y_1^2\sigma (s)e^{-\alpha s}ds
   \end{align*}
   and then
   $$|y_2(t)-y_1(t)| \leq C|\gamma_2-\gamma_1|+2\gamma_2 \int_t^\infty \sigma (s)|y_2(s)-y_1(s)|\, ds.
   $$
   Gronwall's lemma (with initial point $\infty$, same proof as in the usual case) gives
   $|y_2(t)-y_1(t)| \leq C|\gamma_2-\gamma_1| \exp{\int_t^\infty 2 \gamma_2 \sigma (s)ds} \leq K|\gamma_2-\gamma_1|$.
6. Since $y_0(0)=0$ to show that there exists $\gamma$ such that $y_\gamma (0)= \frac 23$ it suffices to show that $\limsup_{\gamma \to \infty} y_\gamma (0)=1$.

If not, $y_\gamma (0)^2 \leq 1-\delta$ for $\gamma$ large and, since $y_\gamma $ is decreasing,  the integral equation yields
$$
y_\gamma (t)\geq \delta \gamma e^{\alpha t} \int_t^\infty \sigma (s) e^{-\alpha s}\, ds \to \infty
$$
as $\gamma \to \infty$, in contrast with $0 \leq y_\gamma \leq 1$ for all $\gamma$.